# What is wrong with choice C algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

1. Consider the following method, isSorted, which is intended to return true if an array of integers is sorted in nondecreasing order and to return false otherwise.

> @return true if the values in the array appear in sorted (nondecreasing) order

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] data)
{
    /* missing code */ 
}
```

Which of the following can be used to replace /* missing code */ so that isSorted will work as intended?

I.

```
for (int k = 1; k < data.length; k++) {
    if (data[k - 1] > data[k])
        return false;
}
return true;
```

II.

```
for (int k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
    if (data[k] > data[k + 1])
        return false;
}
return true;
```

III.

```
for (int k = 0; k < data.length - 1; k++) {
    if (data[k] > data[k + 1])
        return false;
    else
        return true;
 }
 return true;
```

(A) I only
(B) II only
(C) III only
(D) I and II only
(E) I and III only

The solution is A, However, I do not see why choice III does not work. My answer is E, the solution is A.

Comment: Homework? What the actual problem? (otherwise, this is not the right forum)

Comment: Choice III will cause the function to return prematurely

Comment: The AP test is the day after tomorrow, some questions that I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

III is wrong because it will `return` from the first iteration (when k = 0)

```
for (int k = 0; k < data.length - 1; k++) {
if (data[k] > data[k + 1]) // it either return true or false from the first iteration
    return false; // from first iteration, this can return false
 else
    return true; // if the previous didn't return true, this for sure will return false
 }
 return true;
```

Therefore, not the whole array elements are compared, so III is wrong

Comment: @user3602741 no prob, if you don't have other questions please mark as solved :)